# Regex - Exact match start to end

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

There seems to be a small confliction of my multi-line usage.. Here is the context

```
test-test-3
test-1
```

I'm trying to regex exact match each line, Giving it the `test` string and it returns what after `-`:

```
/test-(.*)/i
```

**This** would catch 1st which is `test-test-3`, I want to catch the literal second line `test-1`

I'm trying to make an exact match for what I'm looking for from the beginning of the line to its end ( 1 match ), Using `^` and `$` is not working, Probably because I'm using multi lines (\n),

I tried this : `/^test-(.*)$/i` and `/^test-(.*)\n$/i` Which are not valid

Comment: what will be your expected output ?

Comment: You already hinted at the solution. Use the multi-line flag.

Comment: Edited, More clear now

Comment: @mario Just tried, Doesn't work.. It catches them both

Comment: Are you using `preg_match_all` or `preg_match`? `preg_match` only returns the first match, you have to use `preg_match_all` to get them all.

Comment: I want to use preg_match to exact EXACT string, starting from the beginning of the line to the end to return only one, not them all

Comment: Well, the `.*` any-chars match will obviously detect both. You need a placeholder for just numbers, if that's what it's supposed to find.

Comment: @mario Makes sense but what if second line starts with number ? I want to make end search until there's line break

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eO6wM1/1 ? Is this desired output?

Comment: I think i only had to use \n before $, Had to blame tab spaces being used in my tool. This currently works : `/^test-(.*)\n$/m`

Edit : Accepted answer is exactly right. `\n` as the beginning of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the second line, you need to put a literal `\n` in the regexp at the beginning, because `^` matches the beginning of the first line, too.

```
$str = "test-test-3
test-1";
preg_match('/\ntest-(.*)$/mi', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/qutAx0)